# Second Greatest Value Displaying As "undefined"

Tags: javascript

All variables below are integer values of a range input slider. The code below should log the second greatest value of the sliders to the console. For example, if sliderA = 2, sliderB = 3, and sliderC = 4, the number 3 should be logged to the console. Instead, I'm getting the output "undefined". The code below works when the function is called with integers instead of variables. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
var AS = Number(getNumber("animalsSlide"));
var MS = Number(getNumber("mathSlide"));
var CS = Number(getNumber("cookingSlide"));
var BS = Number(getNumber("biologySlide"));
var PS = Number(getNumber("performingSlide"));
var WS = Number(getNumber("writingSlide"));
var CAS = Number(getNumber("creativeSlide"));
var IS = Number(getNumber("inventingSlide"));

function secondGreatest(arr_num) {
   arr_num.sort(function(x,y) {
      return x-y;
   });
   var uniqa = [arr_num[0]];
   var result = [];
   
   for(var j=1; j < arr_num.length; j++) {
      if(arr_num[j-1] !== arr_num[j]) {
         uniqa.push(arr_num[j]);
      }
   }

   result.push(uniqa[uniqa.length-2]);
   return result.join(',');
}

console.log(secondGreatest([AS,MS,CS,BS,PS,WS,CAS,IS]));
```

Comment: btw, how `getNumber` returns a value which is not a number?

Comment: @NinaScholz You can convert a string into a number using Number("  "), and if the string doesn't convert properly to a number, the output will be "undefined" or "NaN".

Comment: it was a semantic question ...

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the second large value of the sorted array.

```js
const
    values = [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    second = values.find(((last, count = 0) => value => {
        if (last !== value) {
            count++;
            last = value;
        }
        return count === 2;
    })());

console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

since it works with integers and not strings, I assume the problem is with the `getNumber` function.
do you have code there that finds the slider by id?
something like this:

```
let getNumber = (sliderId) => { 
    return +document.getElementById(sliderId).value;
}
```

since the name of the function is `getNumber` it's easy to assume it returns a number and not a string, so that's what I did here.. and then you won't need to parse to number outside

```
var AS =  getNumber("animalsSlide");
var MS =  getNumber("mathSlide");
var CS =  getNumber("cookingSlide");
var BS =  getNumber("biologySlide");
var PS =  getNumber("performingSlide");
var WS =  getNumber("writingSlide");
var CAS = getNumber("creativeSlide");
var IS =  getNumber("inventingSlide");
```